# how to aggregate multiple rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have data frame ["Trading_date","volume"]. how to create new data frame in which:
aggregate multiple rows of the same trading date into one row and sum all the volumes.

Comment: Please provide a **[mcve]**.

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html

Comment: see pandas docs before asking here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job - 
`df.groupby('Trading_date').agg({'volume': 'sum'})`

Please have a look on pandas relevant documentation - 
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html